# PCI 2.1 NIC in 2.0 slot

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

I recently bought a cheap [NIC](http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/268169/icidu-gigabit-pci-card.html) which I think has a x8 PCI slot. On the box it says: "Compatible with PCI revision 2.1/2.2/2.3".

I want to use this in the [MSI H81M-E34](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/H81ME34.html#hero-overview). On the site from MSI it says that the motherboard has 1x PCI 2.0 x16 and 2x PCI 2.0 x1 slot.

I searched on the web and almost everybody says that it's backwards compatible but it will not fit in either the x16 or x1 slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re confusing “[PCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI)” and “[PCI Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express)”. They are not compatible. Your board does not have a PCI slot at all. So you cannot use this NIC.